# SVG/CSS animated icon not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to implement an animated menu icon I found on codepen by Balaj Marius. The design is [here](http://codepen.io/mariusbalaj/pen/fxzCG/).

When I try it in my project (or even independently in separate files), it doesn't work. The icon appears, but the javascript doesn't seem to be running. I'm assuming it's an obvious answer, but it's currently beating me. Any ideas on how to get it up and running?

Here is how I have it:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type="text/javascript" href="js/main.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

        <h2>Scroll to see the magic.</h2>

        <div class="header__fake">

            <div class="icn__wrap">
                <i class="icn__hamburger"></i>
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58px" height="58px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6.215" transform="rotate(90 8 8)"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <i class="btm__border"></i>

        </div>


        <h1>Tah-da!<span>Now scroll back up.</span></h1>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
  background: #02021a url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/balajmarius/hamburger-animation/master/assets/img/bg.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Open sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight:lighter;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.content {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 35px 0 0;
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1000px 0 200px;
}

.content h1 span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

.content .header__fake {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  width: 320px;
}

.content .header__fake i {
  display: block;
}

.content .header__fake .btm__border {
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 58px;
  position: relative;
  height: 58px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap .icn__hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-6px);
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap .icn__hamburger:after,
.content .header__fake .icn__wrap .icn__hamburger:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap .icn__hamburger:before {
  margin: 6px 0 0;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap svg {
  z-index: 10;
}

.content .header__fake .icn__wrap svg circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 39 39;
  stroke-dashoffset: -39;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
}

.content .header__fake.animated .btm__border {
  left: 100%;
  right: 4px;
}

.content .header__fake.animated svg circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s;
}

.content .header__fake.fix .btm__border {
  -webkit-animation: fix 0.2s linear;
  animation: fix 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  right: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fix {
  from {
    right: 5px;
  }

  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fix {
  from {
    right: 5px;
  }

  to {
    right: 0;
  }
```

}

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("ready");
$header = $('.header__fake');

$(window).scroll(function() {


    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 20) {
        $header.addClass('animated').removeClass('fix');
    } else {
        $header.removeClass('animated').addClass('fix');
    }


});

});
```

Comment: Where are you including your javascript?

Comment: Can you see the "ready" in your console.log?

Comment: The only javascript I'm using is what I have above, the js file I link to in my <head>.

Comment: And I can't see the "ready" in console